# Cannot parse decimal number entered using non-English keyboard on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, number-formatting, cultureinfo

In my Windows Phone 8 application I have a text box which uses **InputScopeNameValue.Number** to elicit a currency amount from the user.

The OnBackKeyPress override is parsing the string value of the text box into a decimal value:

```
    base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
    decimal price = 0m;

    var value = PriceControl.PropertyValue;
    NumberStyles style = NumberStyles.Number;
    CultureInfo culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PriceControl.PropertyValue) || 
        decimal.TryParse(value, style, culture, out price))
    {
        App.ViewModel.SelectedProduct.Price = price;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

Everything works as expected for en-US, but once I switch the Region setting of the Windows Phone emulator to de-CH (Switzerland, but other European cultures such as de-DE have the same issue) the following things happen:

- **The on-screen keyboard now shows a ',' (comma)** rather than a '.' (period) along with keys for the digits
- The **culture.NumberFormat.CurrrencyDecimal.Separator is still '.'** as is the **culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator (period)**. Therefore the decimal number entered using the keyboard cannot be successfully parsed!

Is there a way around this? The mismatch between the separator symbol on the keyboard (comma) and the separator in the corresponding NumberFormat seems strange.

Comment: did you change both Keyboard and Language and Region settings in Windows Phone ?

Comment: What is `culture` after you've changed language? I'd expect the decimal separator to change with the culture...

Comment: @JonSkeet Hey John, don't smuggle my points, i was trying to solve this one :))

Comment: In worst case, can't you do a `string.Replace(",", ".")`?

Answer (score 0):

In your `decimal.TryParse` use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of current culture.